# git checkout-index for only recently committed files

Tags: git, version-control

I use this command to copy the committed files into a temporary folder:

```
git checkout-index -a -f --prefix=tmp-export/
```

I wish to limit this to ONLY the files that changed in the last 30 days.
This gets me the list of those files:

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only --since="30 days ago" | sort /unique
```

I've tried a few things but can't seem to make it work where I pipe this list into the first git command.
"is not in the cache" is the error I get when providing my own list of files via this command:

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only --since="30 days ago" | sort /unique | git checkout-index -f --prefix=tmp-export/ --stdin
```

Any help appreciated!

Note: Running Git on Windows 10

Comment: What shell are you using ? Try running it from `git-bash`.

Comment: `sort -u` if you get the linux variant

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The step making the list unique was causing the problems.
Not sure if it causes more work, but skipping this step solved the problem.
I also turned on quiet mode (-q) so no warnings are given for the first line that is empty.

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only --since="30 days ago" | git checkout-index -f -q --prefix=tmp-export-tst/ --stdin
```